# Creating a Custom View and XML Namespace

Tags: android

I am trying to make custom Views in android I mention all my arrtrs list in MainActivity and the XML file but I there is an error in `main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customviews.piechart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.customviews.charting.piechart.MainActivity
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        custom:titleText="Background color"
        custom:valueColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the error.. paste logcat data

Comment: Is com.example.customviews.charting.piechart.MainActivity really a view? You need to post more stuff to get an answer.

Comment: in my opinion `com.example.customviews.charting.piechart.MainActivity` is not extending `View` , or if it is you need a better way of naming your classes / views.

Comment: it gives error at <com.example.customviwes.charting.piechart.MainActivity   that no resource found

Comment: ok now the error has removed but application do not start

Comment: @StinePike here is my logcat data   FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.customviews.charting.piechart/com.example.customviews.charting.piechart.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.customviews.charting.piechart.MainActivity; no empty constructor

Comment: if app is targeting API greater than 17 just add xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" to parent node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a constructor with no arguments?

You should add a constructor like:

```
public MainActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

or

```
public MainActivity(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
```

You asked for a simple example of a custom view:

```
public class BirdView extends ImageView {

private float direction = 0;
Paint paint = new Paint();

public BirdView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public BirdView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
}

public BirdView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec),
            MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    int stratX = getWidth() / 2;
    int startY = getHeight() / 2;
    canvas.rotate(direction, stratX, startY);
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
    canvas.drawLine(stratX, startY, stratX, startY + 80, paint);
}

public void update(float dir) {
    direction = dir;
    invalidate();
}
```

}

Comment: yes i have constructor but in logcat it gives error  Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.customviews.charting.piechart/com.example.customviews.charting.piechart.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.customviews.charting.piechart.MainActivity; no empty constructor

Comment: I think that the constructor with no arguments is the problem. Could you wrap inside that one: public MainActivity(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

Comment: Here is the code   public class MainActivity extends View {

 

  public MainActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);} still i have problem same problem in other code also

Comment: Did your class originally had a constructor like this: 'public MainActivity() {
}' without parameters?

Comment: would you please suggest me simple example that how to make custom view in android

Comment: Sorry for the delay... hope this is still helpful. I edtied the answer to include a simple example of a custom view